# Remove inline CSS attribute from a subtag

Tags: jquery, css, inline

I used this code:

**jQuery**

```
$('a').css("line-height", "null") or

$('a').removeAttr('style');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="categories">
    <nav>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="first"> <a class="page_item_first" href="" title="Home" style="line-height: 158px;">Home</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

But it didn't work.

Any advice please?

Comment: It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/cWLr6/

Comment: Are you running your script before your HTML is loaded?

Comment: Put your script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Maybe wrap your jQuery code with $(document).ready(function(){//your code});

Comment: oooooh! Thank you all! You had right! I load the code before HTML loaded. I put it as you mentioned at the bottom of my page and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works.

Load your Javascript/Jquery scripts at the bottom of your page.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" >< /script> is this the right librady, cause it doesn't work! Also, i want to remove the line-height attribute only from this li tag, not from all the <li> tags in my html code. Thank you Damon!

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .first_a
    {
         line-height:158px;
    }
</style>

<div id="categories">
<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="first"> <a class="page_item_first first_a" href="" title="Home">Home</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and jQuery

```
$('a').removeClass('first_a');
```

and you can add this style again using

```
$('a').addClass('first_a');
```

And you must be sure that your jQuery codes must be **BELOW** the javaScript tag link to jQuery.js

Answer (score 0):

The follow code will remove only the line-height property from the **ul** with id = "nav"

If you have another inline style in the **li**, it may be better than remove the whole style property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav li a').css("line-height", "")
});
```

You can check it working here.
http://jsfiddle.net/cWLr6/